# PHP: get numeric value in the end of a given formatted string

Tags: php, substr, strlen

I "inherited" a buggy PHP page. I'm not an expert of this language but I think I found the origin of the bug. Inside a loop, the page sends a formatted string to the server: the string I found in the HTML page is like this one:

```
2011-09-19__full_1
```

so, it seems we have three parts:

- a date (0,10);
- a string (10,6);
- a final number (17,1);

The code the handles this situation is the following:

```
$datagrid[] = array("date"=>substr($post_array_keys[$i], 0, 10),"post_mode"=>substr($post_array_keys[$i], 10, 6),"class_id"=>substr($post_array_keys[$i], 17, 1),"value"=>$_POST[$post_array_keys[$i]]);
```

What happens: **the final number can contain more than one character**, so this piece:

```
"class_id"=>substr($post_array_keys[$i], 17, 1)
```

is not correct because it seems to retrieve only one character starting from the 17th (and this seems to cause strange behaviors to the website).

Being the whole number the last part of the string, to get the entire number **could I safely change this line this way?**

```
"class_id"=>substr($post_array_keys[$i], 17, strlen($post_array_keys[$i])-17);
```

Comment: Don't know, what you want to hear, but only the author can give you a clear answer. Or some time spent in code analysis. @Jon: `offset=17` and `length-17` _is_ from 17 to the end. However, it is more obvious, when you (@Lotus) just omit the third parameter (which means "till the end")

Comment: Please, add `var_dump(array("date"=>substr($post_array_keys[$i], 0, 10),"post_mode"=>substr($post_array_keys[$i], 10, 6),"class_id"=>substr($post_array_keys[$i], 17, 1),"value"=>$_POST[$post_array_keys[$i]]));` to your post to see the problem completely

Comment: @KingCrunch Ah yes, wonder what function I'm getting mixed up with. Oh well. Edited ta.

You could use explode() (although the double underscore could be a pain). Or another alternative would be regex, which would be simple enough. Just sayin'.

Comment: The problem with splitting is the fact that (sorry for omitting this), another known possibility is that it could be the string "_ empty _" too. @King: ok, I'll omit the third parameter. What I wanted to know was if my idea was good. Anyway, I can't contact the developer simply because he doesn't want to be called and talk to his ex-colleagues (personal reasons...)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the code the way you suggest you would get the numbers at the end starting in position 17. The original code gets only the first digit. Your code would get all the digits.

And it seems you did your homework the line

```
$datagrid[] = array("date"=>substr($post_array_keys[$i], 0, 10),"post_mode"=>substr($post_array_keys[$i], 10, 6),"class_id"=>substr($post_array_keys[$i], 17, 1),"value"=>$_POST[$post_array_keys[$i]]);
```

does give you a very good clue of what you should expect in the variable:

```
first 10 is the date
then you have 6 chars for post_mode
then you have 1 char for class_id
```

If you also confirmed that sometimes the class_id can be more than 1 char, your suggested change would give you the complete class_id at the end.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
$array =  explode("_", $string);
```

this functions returns an array with the elements in the string delimited by "_".

I suggest this because the double underscore may hide another value that is empty in that particular case.

Comment: This would work if the underscore was a delimiter. But based on the information he provided, it seems that the underscores are part of the second field (post_mode), not a delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only the last integer causing trouble, you can use strrchr to get the "tail" of the string, starting with the last '_'.

Comment: I don't think he can assume that there will always be a underscore before the last part of the string. It seems that the underscore is part of the second field (post_mode), not a delimiter. His solution would always get the string starting on position 17.